# Why I'm getting "could not find function "theme_rect"" in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying this code to regenerate this function to plot a network based on this [link](https://sumtxt.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/visualizing-networks-with-ggplot2-in-r/) work, I know some functions are deprecated, I replaced opts with theme, but I got error with theme_rect

```
library(network)
library(ggplot2)
library(sna)
library(ergm)
 
 
plotg <- function(net, value=NULL) {
    m <- as.matrix.network.adjacency(net) # get sociomatrix
    # get coordinates from Fruchterman and Reingold's force-directed placement algorithm.
    plotcord <- data.frame(gplot.layout.fruchtermanreingold(m, NULL)) 
    # or get it them from Kamada-Kawai's algorithm: 
    # plotcord <- data.frame(gplot.layout.kamadakawai(m, NULL)) 
    colnames(plotcord) = c("X1","X2")
    edglist <- as.matrix.network.edgelist(net)
    edges <- data.frame(plotcord[edglist[,1],], plotcord[edglist[,2],])
    plotcord$elements <- as.factor(get.vertex.attribute(net, "elements"))
    colnames(edges) <-  c("X1","Y1","X2","Y2")
    edges$midX  <- (edges$X1 + edges$X2) / 2
    edges$midY  <- (edges$Y1 + edges$Y2) / 2
    pnet <- ggplot()  + 
            geom_segment(aes(x=X1, y=Y1, xend = X2, yend = Y2), 
                data=edges, size = 0.5, colour="grey") +
            geom_point(aes(X1, X2,colour=elements), data=plotcord) +
            scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1") +
            scale_x_continuous(breaks = NA) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = NA) +
            # discard default grid + titles in ggplot2 
            theme(panel.background = theme_minimal()) + theme(legend.position="none")+
            theme(axis.title.x = theme_minimal(), axis.title.y = theme_minimal()) +
            theme( legend.background = theme_rect(colour = NA)) + 
            theme(panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA)) + 
            theme(panel.grid.minor = theme_minimal(), panel.grid.major = theme_minimal())
    return(print(pnet))
}
 
 
g <- network(150, directed=FALSE, density=0.03)
classes <- rbinom(150,1,0.5) + rbinom(150,1,0.5) + rbinom(150,1,0.5)
set.vertex.attribute(g, "elements", classes)
 
plotg(g)
```

Comment: What happens if you change `theme_rect` to `element_rect`?

Comment: The `theme_` versions of the functions were deprecated back in version 1.0 it looks like and have long since been removed from `ggplot2`. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.1/topics/theme_blank

Comment: Thank you @jared_mamrot it seems it work, but I can't test it because another error is showing `Only elements of the same class can be merged`

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could rewrite the 'theme' section to something like this:

```
library(network)
library(ggplot2)
library(sna)
library(ergm)
 
 
plotg <- function(net, value=NULL) {
    m <- as.matrix.network.adjacency(net) # get sociomatrix
    # get coordinates from Fruchterman and Reingold's force-directed placement algorithm.
    plotcord <- data.frame(gplot.layout.fruchtermanreingold(m, NULL)) 
    # or get it them from Kamada-Kawai's algorithm: 
    # plotcord <- data.frame(gplot.layout.kamadakawai(m, NULL)) 
    colnames(plotcord) = c("X1","X2")
    edglist <- as.matrix.network.edgelist(net)
    edges <- data.frame(plotcord[edglist[,1],], plotcord[edglist[,2],])
    plotcord$elements <- as.factor(get.vertex.attribute(net, "elements"))
    colnames(edges) <-  c("X1","Y1","X2","Y2")
    edges$midX  <- (edges$X1 + edges$X2) / 2
    edges$midY  <- (edges$Y1 + edges$Y2) / 2
    pnet <- ggplot()  + 
            geom_segment(aes(x=X1, y=Y1, xend = X2, yend = Y2), 
                data=edges, size = 0.5, colour="grey") +
            geom_point(aes(X1, X2,colour=elements), data=plotcord) +
            scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1") +
            scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
            # discard default grid + titles in ggplot2 
            theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position="none")+
            theme(legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA)) + 
            theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA))
    return(print(pnet))
}
 
 
g <- network(150, directed=FALSE, density=0.03)
classes <- rbinom(150,1,0.5) + rbinom(150,1,0.5) + rbinom(150,1,0.5)
set.vertex.attribute(g, "elements", classes)
 
plotg(g)
```

Comment: Thank you @Jared_mamrot I get this Error: Invalid breaks specification. Use NULL, not NA

Comment: I have edited my answer to change 'NA' to 'NULL'